# WPF floating draggable always on top button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, mvvm

I'm now working on WPF application. I need to build floating draggable button that stick on top of my window. Something like the Facebook messenger app in android:
[image: facebook messenger app in android]

I found out that Dropbox is able to do it. Exactly like what I want. If you install dropbox in your Windows, when open an Office document in your dropbox folder, you will see something like this:
[image: dropbox floating button in Windows]

After spending long hour trying to find out a way to achieve this, the mighty google return nothing about suchs a thing for WPF application.

If anyone know how to do this, either by 3rd party tool or build from scratch, please enlighten me. Thank you.